# Angle between two vectors under embedding

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ be two Riemannian manifolds . Suppose $f: M\to N$ be an embedding then

> Is there relation between angle of two vectors in $M$ and its images in $N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only thing you can say is that linearly independent vectors map to linearly independent vectors. Of course, if $f$ is an isometric embedding, then the angles will match.